# Weighted Average in access

Tags: ms-access

I have a table in which I have the following columns

```
FirstDate,
LastDate,
Grade_Category,
CR_Tones,
CR_grade
```

I created a query where this data is grouped by date and material type.

I need to see at the end of the grade column weighted average of the Grade with Tones.
Table is as below:
[image]

This is a query that I have designed and I have grouped movement date, grade category, etc the summed up tones, etc.

Answer (score 0):

A query like below can be good starting point

```
 select  
        lastdate as [date], 
        grade_category as [material type],
        SUM(CR_grade*CR_Tones)/SUM(CR_Tones) as [weighted grade]

 from table

 group by lastdate, grade_category
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are looking for grouping sets

```
 select  
        lastdate as [date], 
        grade_category as [material type],
        SUM(CR_grade*CR_Tones)/SUM(CR_Tones) as weightedgrade --your formula for weighted grade
 from yourtable
 group by Grouping Sets (lastdate, grade_category)
```